# RxJava: Conditionally catch error and stop propagation

Tags: java, error-handling, rx-java, observable, retrofit2

I use Retrofit with RxJava Observables and lambda expressions. I'm new to RxJava and cannot find out how to do the following:

```
Observable<ResponseBody> res = api.getXyz();
res.subscribe(response -> {
    // I don't need the response here
}, error -> {
    // I might be able to handle an error here. If so, it shall not go to the second error handler.
});
res.subscribe(response -> {
    // This is where I want to process the response
}, error -> {
    // This error handler shall only be invoked if the first error handler was not able to handle the error.
});
```

I looked at the [error handling operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling-Operators), but I don't understand how they can help me with my usecase.

Comment: First of all, your code as it stands now will execute the network request twice, once for each subscriber - the reason for that is that Retrofit returns "cold" Observables, which will execute only when some Subscriber subscribes to them. Apart from that, could you explain some more about what you want to achieve? Are the two subscriptions in different classes? What do you mean with "handle" the error in each case? And, maybe `onErrorResumeNext` is what you want - it could check whether the error can be "handled" there or not and then either pass the error along or do something else...

Comment: Yes, the two subscriptions are in different classes. I try to do something like this: Create observable for api-request(-response). Then pass that observable to a function that attaches some generic error handlers and returns the (or a new) observable. and finally, subscribe to get the api response or handle any errors which were not handled by the generic error handler.

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:** Keep the two `Subscriber`s but `cache` the `Observable`.

Just keep everything as it is now, but change the first line to:

```
Observable<ResponseBody> res = api.getXyz().cache();
```

The `cache` will make sure that the request is only sent once but that sill both `Subscriber`s get all the same events.

This way whether and how you handle the error in the first `Subscriber` does not affect what the second `Subscriber` sees.

**Method 2:** Catch some errors with `onErrorResumeNext` but forward all others.

Add `onErrorResumeNext` to your `Observable` to produce something like this (in the "inner" object):

```
Observable observable = Observable.error(new IllegalStateException())
.onErrorResumeNext(new Func1<Throwable, Observable<?>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<?> call(Throwable throwable) {
        if (throwable instanceof NumberFormatException) {
            System.out.println("NFE - handled");
            return Observable.empty();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Some other exception - panic!");
            return Observable.error(throwable);
        }
    }
});
```

And only subscribe once (in the "outer" object):

```
observable.subscribe(new Subscriber() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
        System.out.println("onCompleted");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        System.out.println("onError");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(Object o) {
        System.out.println(String.format("onNext: %s", String.valueOf(o)));
    }    

});
```

This way, the error is only forwarded if it cannot be handled in the `onErrorResumeNext` - if it can, the `Subscriber` will only get a call to `onCompleted` and nothing else.

Having side effects in `onErrorResumeNext` makes me a bit uncomfortable, though. :-)

**EDIT:** Oh, and if you want to be extra strict, you could use **Method 3:** Wrap every case in a new object.

```
public abstract class ResultOrError<T> {
}

public final class Result<T> extends ResultOrError<T> {
    public final T result;

    public Result(T result) {
        this.result = result;
    }
}

public final class HandledError<T> extends ResultOrError<T> {
    public final Throwable throwable;

    public Result(Throwable throwable) {
        this.throwable = throwable;
    }
}

public final class UnhandledError<T> extends ResultOrError<T> {
    public final Throwable throwable;

    public Result(Throwable throwable) {
        this.throwable = throwable;
    }
}
```

And then:

- Wrap proper results in `Result` (using `map`)
- Wrap handle-able errors in `HandledError` and
- un-handle-able errors in `UnhandledError` (using `onErrorResumeNext` with an `if` clause)
- handle the `HandledError`s (using `doOnError`)
- have a `Subscriber<ResultOrError<ResponseBody>>` - it will get notifications (`onNext`) for all three types but will just ignore the `HandledError`s and handle the other two types.